# Unit Testing: Creating a 'mock' request to simulate a MVC page request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd

How do I go about creating a mock request for my asp.net-mvc application for unit-testing?

What options do I have?

I am using FormsCollection in my Actions so I can simulate form input data also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to create a new instance of FormCollection and add the data inside of it.

So you can call something like this without mocking anything.

```
var result = controller.Create(new FormCollection { { "InvoiceId", "-1" } }) as RedirectToRouteResult;
```

Otherwise if your code calls something like Request or HttpContext you can use the following extension method (inspired from Scott Hanselman's [example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETMVCSessionAtMix08TDDAndMvcMockHelpers.aspx))

I am using RhinoMocks.

```
public static HttpContextBase SetHttpContext(this MockRepository mocks, Controller controller, HttpCookieCollection cookies) {
cookies = cookies ?? new HttpCookieCollection();

var request = mocks.StrictMock<HttpRequestBase>();
var context = mocks.StrictMock<HttpContextBase>();
var response = mocks.StrictMock<HttpResponseBase>();

SetupResult.For(context.Request).Return(request);
SetupResult.For(context.Response).Return(response);
SetupResult.For(request.Cookies).Return(cookies);
SetupResult.For(request.IsSecureConnection).Return(false);
SetupResult.For(response.Cookies).Return(cookies);

if (controller != null)
{
    controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(context, new RouteData(), controller);
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestUrl))
{
    request.SetupRequestUrl(requestUrl);
    SetupResult.For(response.ApplyAppPathModifier(null)).IgnoreArguments().Return(null);
}

return context;
}
```